# Compare 3 tab delimited files and print matches in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to match column 1 of file 1 with column 1 of file 2 and then column 2 of file 1 with column 1 of file 3 and then print the matches. The columns in the files are separated by tabs. For example:

file 1:

```
fji01dde AIDJFMGKG
dlp02sle VMCFIJGM
cmr03lsp CKEIFJ
```

file 2:

```
fji01dde 25 30
dlp02sle 40 50
cmr03lsp 60 70
```

file 3:

```
AIDJFMGKG
CKEIFJ
```

output needs to be:

```
fji01dde AIDJFMGKG 25 30
cmr03lsp CKEIFJ 60 70
```

I only want lines that are common in all three files.

The below code works well for the first two files, but I need to incorporate the third file. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;

my (%file1,%file2);

## Open the 1st file
open(A,"file1");
while(<A>){
    chomp; 
    ## Split the current line on tabs into the @F array.
    my @F=split(/\t/); 
    push @{$file1{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F];
} 

## Open the 2nd file
open(B,"file2");
while(<B>){
    chomp; 
    ## Split the current line on tabs into the @F array.
    my @F=split(/\t/); 

    if (defined($file1{$F[0]})) {
        foreach my $col (@{$file1{$F[0]}}) {
            print "$F[0]\t$col\t@F[1..$#F]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of those files have lines in common.

Comment: I want to match column 1 of file 1 with column 1 of file 2 and then column 2 of file 1 with column 1 of file 3.

Comment: Then you should update the question. You also want to combine them somehow.

Comment: What would the output be if file3 did not have `CKEIFJ`?

Comment: column 1 of file 3 is a subset of column 2 of file 1

Comment: So what would the output be?

Comment: Then that row should not be printed.  The final output should contain columns 1 and 2 of file 1 and columns 2 and 3 of file 2 for only those rows that contain the file 3 keywords.

Comment: It would be just `fji01dde AIDJFMGKG 25 30`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the output if file 3 did not contain the "CKEIFJ" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm seems to be...

```
for each line in 1
   if 1.1 and 2.1 match  AND
      1.2 appears in 3.1
   then
      combine 1.1, 1.2, 2.2 and 2.3
```

Because there's plenty of edge cases in parsing CSV files, don't do it by hand. Use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS). It can also handle turning CSV files into hashes for us and it's super efficient.

What we'll do is parse all the files. The first file is left as a list, but the other two are put into hashes keyed on the columns that we're going to search on.

NOTE: The names `$data` are horrible, but I don't know what sort of data these files represent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS qw(csv);

my @csv_files = @ARGV;

# Parse all the CSV files into arrays of arrays.
my $data1 = csv( in => $csv_files[0], sep_char => "\t" );

# Parse the other CSV files into hashes of rows keyed on the columns we're going to search on.
my $data2 = csv( in             => $csv_files[1],
                 sep_char       => "\t",
                 headers        => ["code", "num1", "num2"],
                 key => "code"
            );
my $data3 = csv( in             => $csv_files[2],
                 sep_char       => "\t",
                 headers        => ["CODE"],
                 key            => "CODE"
            );

for my $row1 (@$data1) {
    my $row2 = $data2->{$row1->[0]};
    my $row3 = $data3->{$row1->[1]};

    if( $row2 && $row3 ) {
        print join "\t", $row1->[0], $row1->[1], $row2->{num1}, $row2->{num2};
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

This reads all the files into memory. If the files are very large this can be a problem. You can reduce memory usage by iterating through file1 one row at a time instead of slurping it all in.

Comment: *“Because there's plenty of edge cases in parsing CSV files, don't do it by hand”* I very much disagree, particularly with *tab-separated* files. If the data is known not to contain the separator character, and doesn't use quotes, then `chomp; split /\t/;` is all that's necessary. Setting up `Text:CSV` to do a simple split like that is awkward

Comment: "*If the data is known not to contain the separator character, and doesn't use quotes*"... these are famous last words. The consequences usually don't come down on your head, but the poor sap who has to fix it later. Today it might be true. Tomorrow, *who knows* what's going to be in those files? That's the nature of data. Text::CSV_XS is wicked fast and very complete. It has almost no down sides once you have it installed. If you're going to be working with CSV files, it's worth investing the small effort to learn it. It was also less code (and probably faster) to do the key/hash creation.

Comment: I disagree. If the data changes to being tab-separated *and* having tabs within its data then it is very strange data, and unless this is the only code that has to process it then it will cause widespread problems. The whole point of using tab as a separator is that it is highly unlikely to appear in the data, so the nastiness of quotes and escapes isn't necessary